# Shelve import module error python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, shelve

I try to import a custom Class Instance that I shelved but I am getting an:

`Import Error: No module named MyModule`

All my python modules are located within a directory that contains `__init__.py`

Here is my puttoshelve.py template to perform the shelve:

```
from  MyModule import MyModule
import shelve
import copy

mymodule = MyModule()
cmymodule = copy.deepcopy(mymodule)
pathtomyshelve ="/some/path/shelve"
cshelve = shelve.open(pathtomyshelve)
cshelve['object'] = cmymodule
cshelve.close()
```

this actually perform a shelve. If I run an ipython session within the same import shelve and:

```
from MyModule import MyModule
import shelve

pathtomyshelve ="/some/path/shelve"
shelve_p = shelve.open(pathtomyshelve)
obj = shelve_p['object']
obj
```

then I get:

```
{'object': <MyModule.MyModule object at 0x2139510>}
```

**BUT**

When I use my outofshelve.py to retrieve my object, which is basically the same code that I ran from the ipython console, I receive:

`Import Error: No module named MyModule`

What am I missing here? (complete error below)

```
 File "/home/pierre/.qgis2/python/plugins/sig40/sig40_ZR_dialog.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.mymodule = shelve_p['object']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 122, in __getitem__
    value = Unpickler(f).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 454, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named MyModule
```

Comment: Just to Close this Question:

MyModule was referencing some Qt object which prevent to perform the shelf.

I don't know if there is a way to work around this since I abandoned my initial object for a more simple one holding only built-in python object.

Closed.

Answer (score 0):

I had he same Problem when i tried to use my own Logwriter.

I found that solution. (But it is python 3. so the code may change a bit)

```
cDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("logWriter.py"))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(cDir))
import logClasses.logWriter as log
```

My Folder Structure is like that

1. logClasses

   1. **init**.py
   2. logWriter.py
2. mailClasses

   1. **init**.py
   2. sendMail.py <-- This uses the logWriter.py

I hope that solution work for you like it did for me

Comment: I tried without success. All my modules are located within the same package but the shelve.db I try to load has been written in another directory. If i instanciate another mynewmodule = MyModule() it gets build without problem, so MyModule is well imported. If I copy the shelve.db inside my package, i also received no error.

Comment: @PeterPeterson Maybe try appending the path for the shelve.db the same way you would for your MyModul